# Integral involving InverseErf: closed-form expression and asymptotics

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

Consider the integral

```
f[n_] := Integrate[s^(n - 1) InverseErf[1 - 2 s], {s, 0, 1}, 
  Assumptions -> n > 0]
```

a) find a closed form expression of $f$ if possible
b) calculate the exact values of $f(n)$ for $n = 1 .. 6$
c) calculate the asymptotic behaviour of $f(n)$ for $n\to \infty$

J. M. pointed out in a comment that the integral $f$ is equivalent to this one:

```
f1[n_] :=  2^(1 - n)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]*
 Integrate[u Exp[-u^2] Erfc[u]^(n - 1), {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

Remark: $f1$ was my original expression before I found the shorter $f$. But $f1$ has the advantage of containing familiar functions in the integrand rather than the "exotic" `InverseErf[].`

Comment: for `n = 2` wil be: $-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$

Comment: FWIW, your integral is equivalent to $$\frac{2^{1-n}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty u\exp(-u^2)\operatorname{erfc}(u)^{n-1}\mathrm du$$

Comment: @J. M. that's where it came from ;-) But maybe it is better to use this form as this Integrand contains better know functions.

Comment: Yes, this one is better behaved than the one with the inverse error function, numerically speaking.

Comment: I made slight progress: for n = 4, I found after a rather cumbersome procedure f[4] = -(3/8) 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] ]  (1 + 2 /\[Pi] ArcTan[Sqrt[2]/4]) ~= -0.18197. I'm currently checking if the procedure generalizes.

Comment: I'd also recommend asking someone on math.stackexchange.com.  There some real integration wizards on there who may certainly point you in the right direction.

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks, but that's where I came from. I wanted a fresh start here.

Answer (score 7):

We provide a (partial) solution in these sections

- closed-form expressions
- numerical results
- asymptotic behaviour
- discussion

**Closed-form expressions**

Since the original integral is evaluated by Mathematica only for the first two values we shall look here for equivalent expressions for the integral and see if Mathematica performs better with these.

*Equivalent expressions*

First, for easier reading, we give the formulas in Latex, then we write down the Mathematica expressions.

Equivalent expressions for $f(n)$ are (the proof of the equivalences is left to the reader. I confine myself to brief hints, the complete proofs can be provided on request).

$$f1(n)={\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } u \exp \left(-u^2\right) \left(\frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}(u)\right)^{n-1} \, du}$$

Noticing that $\text{erfc} = 1 - \text{erf}$ and expanding the power into a binomial sum gives

$$f2(n) = - \frac{2^{1-n}}{\sqrt{\pi }} \sum _{m=1}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor } g(2 m-1) \binom{n-1}{2m-1}$$

where

$$g(k)={\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } u \exp \left(-u^2\right) \text{erf}(u)^{k} \, du}$$

Notice that $g(k) = 0$ for even $k$. We have already taken this into account in $f2$ where only odd terms contribute.

The following forms are equivalent to $g$ for odd $k$ but they will be considered also for even $k$ in the following

$$g1(k)={2\int_{0 }^{\infty } u \exp \left(-u^2\right) \text{erf}(u)^{k} \, du}$$

Letting $u^2 \to t$ gives

$$g2(k)={\int_{0 }^{\infty } \exp \left(-t \right) \text{erf}(\sqrt{t})^{k} \, du}$$

The next form is a multiple integral over the $k$-dimensional hypercube obtained by inserting the integral representation of $\text{erf}$ into $g2$ and performing the $t$-Integration:

$$g3(k)=\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)^k \Gamma \left(\frac{k}{2}+1\right) \int _0^1 ... \int _0^1\frac{1}{\left(\sum _{i=1}^k y(i)^2+1\right){}^{\frac{k}{2}+1}}dy(1) ... dy(k)$$

The corresponding Mathematica expressions (with the same names) are:

```
f1[n_] := 
 1/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   Integrate[
   u Exp[-u^2] (1/2 Erfc[u])^(n - 1), {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

f2[n_] := 
 2^(1 - n)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   Sum[Binomial[n - 1, k] (-1)^k g[k], {k, 1, n - 1,2}]

g[k_] := Integrate[u Exp[-u^2] Erf[u]^k, {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

g1[k_] := 2 Integrate[u Exp[-u^2] Erf[u]^k, {u, 0, \[Infinity]}]

g2[k_] := Integrate[Exp[-t] Erf[Sqrt[t]]^k, {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]

g3[k_] := 
 (2/Sqrt[\[Pi]])^k Gamma[1 + k/2] Integrate[1/(1 + Sum[y[i]^2, {i, 1, k}])^(1 + k/2), Sequence @@ Table[{y[i], 0, 1}, {i, 1, k}]]
```

*Results*

We have shown that the calculation of $f$ can be traced back to evaluating the function $g$.

It turns out that $g3$ gives closed-form results for the highest $k$:

```
Table[{k, g3[k]}, {k, 1, 3}]
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
 2 & \frac{2 \sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{\pi } \\
 3 & \frac{3 \sqrt{2} \cot ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{2}\right)}{\pi } \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Unfortunately, this "highest $k$ is still very modest. Already $g3(4)$ remains unevaluated.

Looking for a rule in the first 3 terms I came up with

```
gguess[k_] := k Sqrt[2] ArcTan[1/Sqrt[k^2-1]])/\[Pi]}
```

but it doesn't work for $k=4$ as can be seen by numerical comparison.

Finally, using $f2$ with $g3$ (called $f23$) we obtain the closed-form expressions for $f(n)$

```
{#, f23[#]} & /@ {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} // Simplify
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }} \\
 3 & -\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }} \\
 4 & -\frac{3 \cos ^{-1}\left(-1/3\right)}{4 \sqrt{2} \pi ^{3/2}} \\
 5 & -\frac{3 \sqrt{2}}{4 \pi ^{3/2}}\cos ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}-\frac{1}{6}\right)\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

numerically

```
% // N

(* Out[797]= {{1., 0.}, {2., -0.199471}, {3., -0.199471}, {4., -0.18197}, {5., -0.164468}} *)
```

**Numerical results**

Define the numerical analogue to our functions as

```
fn[n_] := NIntegrate[s^(n - 1) InverseErf[1 - 2 s], {s, 0, 1}]

f1n[n_] :=  1/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
   NIntegrate[u Exp[-u^2] (1/2 Erfc[u])^(n - 1), {u, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
```

As expected $f1n$ is faster than $fn$;

```
AbsoluteTiming[fn[10^4]]

(* Out[430]= {1.88997, -0.00027235} *)

AbsoluteTiming[f1n[10^4]]

(* Out[431]= {0.022427, -0.00027235} *)
```

The first few discrete values are (excluding the trivial case $n = 1$), using

```
tfn[nn_] := Table[{n, fn[n] // Chop}, {n, 2, nn}]

tfn[10]

(* Out[676]= 
{
{2, -0.199471}, {3, -0.199471}, {4, -0.18197}, {5, -0.164468}, {6,-0.149342}, {7, -0.136591}, {8, -0.12583}, {9, -0.116674}, {10, -0.108806}
}
```

Notice the agreement with the numerical values of the closed-form expressions for $n = 2..4$ which is also a verification of these.

Plotting it

```
ListPlot[tfn[20], 
  PlotLabel -> "Numerical values of f(n) for n = 2 .. 20", 
  AxesLabel -> {"n", "f(n)"}]
```

[image]

**Asymptotic behaviour**

The asymptotics for large $n$ is most conveniently calculated in the original form of $f$.

The integrand of $f$ is given by

```
fi[n_, s_] := s^(n - 1) InverseErf[1 - 2 s]
```

The "exotic" function `InverseErf[]` does not seem to have an official name (please correct my if I am wrong), hence for brevity we shall call it fre(x) and define

```
fre[x_] := InverseErf[x]
```

The function $\text{fre}$ is, of course, just $\text{erf}$ rotated by $\pi /4$ and looks like this

```
Plot[fre[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotLabel -> "The function fre(x) = InverseErf[x]", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "fre(x)"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The complete integrand for some small values of $n$ is shown here

```
Plot[{fi[2, s], fi[3, s], fi[5, s]}, {s, 0, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> "The integrand for some n\nn = 2 (blue), 3 (yellow), 5 (green)",
  AxesLabel -> {"s", "fi(n,s)"}, PlotRange -> {-2, .2}]
```

[image]

We see that, as expected, for increasing $n$ the appreciable contribution to the integral concentrates around $s = 1$

Close to $s = 1$ the integrand is

```
Simplify[Series[s^(n - 1) fre[1 - 2 x], {x, 1, 1}] // Normal, 0 < x < 1]

(* Out[733]= 
-s^(-1 + n) Sqrt[-Log[1 - x] - 
  1/2 Log[2 \[Pi] (Log[1/(2 \[Pi])] - 2 Log[1 - x])]]
*)
```

First let us look at the plot of $f$ for very large $n$ and try to find analytic expression suggested by the series expansion

```
Plot[{1, - f1n[n] n/Sqrt[(-Log[1/n] - Log[-Log[1/n]])], -f1n[n] n/Sqrt[
    ProductLog[n]], - f1n[n] n/Sqrt[Log[n] ]}, {n, 2, 10^6}, 
 PlotRange -> {0.85, 1.05}, AxesLabel -> {"n", "f/fappr"}, 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Behavior of f for large n\nrelative to various approximations\nfappr ~ \
asympt(ProductLog)/n (yellow)\nfappr ~ \!\(\*SqrtBox[\(ProductLog[n]\)]\)/n \
(green)\nfappr ~ \!\(\*SqrtBox[\(Log[n]\)]\)/n (red)"]
```

[image]

We see that, up to a factor close to unity the asymptotics is best described by

$$f(n)\sim \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{W(n)}$$

where $W(n)$ is the LambertW function (Lambert 1758, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html ) which is the inverse of $n = W \exp (W)$.

An analytic derivation of the asymptotics will be given later.

**Discussion**

*Relation to Laplace transform*

The function $g2$ is in fact a Laplace transform

$$glp(n) = \mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^n\right](s)$$

at $s\to 1$.

The function $g$ in the form $g3$ is easily generalized to the Laplace form by replacing the $1$ before the sum by $s$, and it can be calculated for the powers 1, 2, and 3. Adding the recent discovery of Mariusz Iwaniuk for $g(4)$ (which, however, contains an unevaluated integral) we have

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & \frac{1}{s \sqrt{s+1}} \\
 2 & \frac{4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s+1}}\right)}{\pi  s \sqrt{s+1}} = \frac{4}{\pi  s \sqrt{s+1}}\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s+2}}\right) \\
 3 & \frac{6 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s+1} \sqrt{s+3}}\right)}{\pi  s \sqrt{s+1}} = \frac{6}{\pi  s \sqrt{s+1}}\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s+2}\right)\\
 4 & \frac{4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{s+1}}}{s}-\frac{96 \int_0^{\sqrt{s+1}} \frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a^2+2}\right)}{\left(a^2+1\right) \sqrt{a^2+2}} \, da}{\pi ^2 s \sqrt{s+1}}\\
\end{array}
\right)$$

In the published tables of Laplace transformations (see e.g. http://authors.library.caltech.edu/43489/1/Volume%201.pdf 4.12 (4)) I have found only the case $n = 1$, hence, as a byproduct of this study, we can add two closed-form expressions and one with an integral left to the tables.

**EDIT 06.02.2017**

Mariusz Iwaniuk pointed out in a comment that

$$g2(4,s) = \frac{4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{s+1}}}{s}-\frac{96 \int_0^{\sqrt{s+1}} \frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{a^2+2}\right)}{\left(a^2+1\right) \sqrt{a^2+2}} \, da}{\pi ^2 s \sqrt{s+1}}$$

and that the remaining integral is related to Ahmed's integral (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5169.pdf).

The numerical check $g2(4,s=1) = g2n(4)$ is ok.

The integral we need is not Ahmed's integral but a generalization of it. The upper integration limit is not unity but $\sqrt{1+s}$.

**EDIT 07.02.2017**

In an attempt to "crack" the remaining integral I have defined some integrals appearing naturally in this context, and have derived relations between these (they include the relation of my comment).

The integrals are

$$M(s)=\int_0^{\sqrt{s+1}} \frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{y^2+2}\right)}{\left(y^2+1\right) \sqrt{y^2+2}} \, dy\tag{7.1}$$

$$B(s)= \int_0^1 \frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{y^2+2}}{\sqrt{s+1}}\right)}{\left(y^2+1\right) \sqrt{y^2+2}} \, dy\tag{7.2}$$

$$C(s) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^s \frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z+3}\right)}{\sqrt{z+1} (z+2) \sqrt{z+3}} \, dz\tag{7.3}$$

Note added on 15.02.17:

While trying to understand the recent EDIT of Mariusz Iwaniuk I found that the integral C can be transformed into a simpler form by the substitution $z\to \frac{1}{\sin (w)}-2$

$$C_1(s) = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s+2}\right)}^{\frac{\pi }{6}} \cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\csc (w)+1}\right) \, dw\tag{7.3.1}$$

The relations are

$$M(s)=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s+1}\right)-B(s) \tag {7.4}$$

$$B(s)=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s+1}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2}{32} -C(s)\tag{7.5}$$

and, combining these two gives the interesting relation

$$M(s)=\frac{\pi ^2}{32} + C(s)\tag{7.6}$$

It turns out that, for the case of the OP, i.e. $s=1$, the main part of $M(1)$ is given by the explicit fraction, and only about 13% are due to integral $C(1)$.

In fact, numerically for $s=1$ the equation reads (in the above order)

0.3540215 = 0.3084251+0.0455963, and the relation is 0.0455963/0.3540215 = 0.128795.

We can find a good approximate expression for $C$. In fact, since $\cot^{-1}$ is a decreasing function we can replace it in the integrand by its maximum value $ \cot^{-1}\left(\sqrt{3}\right)$ to obtain an upper bound (i.e. the function in question is smalller). Now the integral can be performed, and the result for $M$ becomes

$$M(s) \lesssim \frac{\pi ^2}{288}+\frac{1}{6} \pi  \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{s+1}{s+3}}\right)$$

Notice: I have the derivation and some corollaries ready in draft state, but I have to beg for your patience as it takes some time for me to type it in.

**EDIT 08.02.17: Generating function and difference-differential equation**

Remember that we wish to calculate the Laplace-transformation of the n-th power of the Erf-function of a square root

$$glp(n,s)=\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^n\right](s)$$

Here's a new idea: instead of looking into single powers we try to "untie the Gordian knot" and cover them all at once.

This is generally done using generating functions. It is convenient here to use the exponential generating function

$$h(z, s)=\int_0^{\infty } \exp (-s t) \exp \left(-z\; \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)\right) \, dt\tag{8.1}$$

After some manipulations including partial integration combined with differentiation I came up with this equation for the generating function

$$ddeq=s (s+1) \frac{\partial h(z,s)}{\partial s}+\left(\frac{3 s}{2}+1\right) h(z,s) -\frac{z^2 h(z,s+2)}{\pi }=\frac{1}{2}\tag{8.2}$$

This is a linear inhomogeneous partial difference-differential equation of first order.

This type of equation is new to me. Hence I don't know yet how to approach a solution.

Some first observations

1) the "generating" parameter $z$ appears only in one position as a factor

2) if $z = 0$, the eqation reduces to a simple ODE which can readily be solved with a simple result

```
DSolve[ddeq /. z -> 0, h[0, s], s]

(* {{h[0, s] -> 1/s + C[1]/(s Sqrt[1 + s])}} *)
```

The first part is simply $glp(n=0,s)$, as it should be. It is interesting that the next term $glp(n=1,s)$ also appears automatically.

**EDIT 18.10.17: Derivation of the difference-differential equation**

It's my pleasure to comply with Mariusz Iwaniuk's recent request and present the details of the derivation of equ. (8.2).

The text needs some formatting, sorry.

The derivation consists of a chain of partial integrations and derivatives.

§1)
We consider the expression

```
D[Exp[-s t] Exp[-z Erf[Sqrt[t]]], t] // Expand

-E^(-s t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) s - (E^(-t - s t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) z)/(
 Sqrt[\[Pi]] Sqrt[t])
```

Integrating over t gives

```
Exp[-s t] Exp[-z Erf[Sqrt[t]]] /. t -> 0

1

Limit[Exp[-s t] Exp[-z Erf[Sqrt[t]]], t -> \[Infinity], Assumptions -> s > 0]

0
```

Hence

```
1 == s Integrate[E^(-s t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) , {t, 0, \[Infinity]}] + 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Integrate[E^(-t - s t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/ Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]

(* 1 *) 1 == 
 s h[z, s] + 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Integrate[E^(-(s + 1) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/ Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

Differentiating the equation with respect to s gives

```
0 = D[s h[z, s], s] + 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Integrate[
    D[E^(-t - s t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/ Sqrt[t], s], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

but

```
D[E^(-t - s t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/ Sqrt[t], s]

-E^(-t - s t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t]
```

inserting this gives

```
(* 2 *) 0 = 
 D[s h[z, s], s] - 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Integrate[E^(-(s + 1) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

§2 2nd partial integration

Consider
(notice that we have s+1 now)

```
D[E^(-t (1 + s) - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], t] // Expand

E^(-(1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/(2 Sqrt[t]) - 
 E^(-(1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t] - 
 E^(-(1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) s Sqrt[t] - (
 E^(-t - (1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) z)/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
```

Integrating this expression gives zero since

```
Limit[E^(-t (1 + s) - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], t -> 0]

0

Limit[E^(-t (1 + s) - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], t -> \[Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> s > 0]

0

0 == Integrate[E^(-(1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/(
   2 Sqrt[t]), {t, 0, \[Infinity]}] - (1 + s) Integrate[
    E^(-(1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}] - 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Integrate[E^(-(s + 2) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) , {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

or, noticing that the last integral is h(z,s+2), i.e. h(z,s) with s shifted by two units,

```
(* 3 *) Integrate[E^(-(1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/(
  2 Sqrt[t]), {t, 
   0, \[Infinity]}] == (1 + s) Integrate[
    E^(-(1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}] + 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]] h[z, s + 2]
```

Now the left hand side of (* 3 *) can be replaced using (* 1 *)

```
(* 1 rep. *) 1 == 
 s h[z, s] + 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Integrate[E^(-(s + 1) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/ Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

or

```
Integrate[E^(-(s + 1) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]])/( 
  2 Sqrt[t]), {t, 0, \[Infinity]}] == Sqrt[\[Pi]]/(2 z) (1 - s h[z, s])
```

giving

```
Sqrt[\[Pi]]/(
  2 z) (1 - s h[z, s]) == (1 + s) Integrate[
    E^(-(1 + s) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}] + 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]] h[z, s + 2]
```

Now on the r.h.s. of (* 3 *)  we use (*2 *)

```
(* 2 rappel *) 0 = 
 D[s h[z, s], s] - 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
    Integrate[E^(-(s + 1) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

or

```
Integrate[E^(-(s + 1) t - z Erf[Sqrt[t]]) Sqrt[t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}] == 
 Sqrt[\[Pi]]/z D[s h[z, s], s]
```

to get from (* 3 *)

```
(* 3a *)  Sqrt[\[Pi]]/(
  2 z) (1 - s h[z, s]) == (1 + s) Sqrt[\[Pi]]/z D[s h[z, s], s] + 
  z/Sqrt[\[Pi]] h[z, s + 2]
```

simplifying and sorting

```
1/2 (1 - s h[z, s]) == (1 + s) D[s h[z, s], s] + z^2/\[Pi] h[z, s + 2]

1/2 (1 - s h[z, s]) == (1 + s) (h[z, s] + s D[h[z, s], s]) + 
  z^2/\[Pi] h[z, s + 2]

1/2 (1 - s h[z, s]) == (1 + s) h[z, s] + (1 + s) s D[h[z, s], s] + 
  z^2/\[Pi] h[z, s + 2]

1/2 - s /2 h[z, s] - (1 + s) h[z, s] - 
  z^2/\[Pi] h[z, s + 2] == (1 + s) s D[h[z, s], s]
```

gives finally the equation

```
(* 4 *) ddeq = (1 + s) s D[h[z, s], s] + (1 + (3 s )/2) h[z, s] - 
    z^2/\[Pi] h[z, s + 2] == 1/2;
```

End of derivation of (8.2).

Comment: +1 - I always enjoy reading your analyses...

Comment: @ciao Thank you for your kind comment. It encourages me to continue and share my fun.

Comment: $\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^4\right](s)=\frac{4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{1+s}}}{s}-\frac{96 \int_0^{\sqrt{s+1}}
   \frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{2+a^2}\right)}{\left(1+a^2\right) \sqrt{2+a^2}} \, da}{\pi ^2 s \sqrt{1+s}}$ and solve Ahmed's integral http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AhmedsIntegral.html

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Very interesting result. Numerically it is correct. How did you derive it? The difference to Ahmed's integral is that here we need the indefinite integral, or at least one with a variable upper Integration limit, or at least with the upper limit equal to $\sqrt 2$, corresponding to $s=1$.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk After some manipulations I end up with this integral to be calculated: $$\int_0^1 \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s+1}}{\sqrt{y^2+2}}\right)}{\left(y^2+1\right) \sqrt{y^2+2}} \, dy$$ This is a generalization of Ahmed's integral differing from it by the factor $\sqrt {1+s}$ under the $\tan ^-1$

Comment: I can write how I derive this integral,but a lot of writing here and will not fit in comment. :-)

Comment: You could put your derivation in another answer to my OP.

Comment: @J. M. you might wish to have a look at my last EDIT (08.02.17) with an interesting difference-differential equation for the generating function of the Laplace transform of the powers of Erf.

Comment: @QuantumDot you might wish to have a look at my last EDIT (08.02.17) with an interesting difference-differential equation for the generating function of the Laplace transform of the powers of Erf.

Comment: @ciao you might wish to have a look at my last EDIT (08.02.17) with an interesting difference-differential equation for the generating function of the Laplace transform of the powers of Erf.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. You might wish to have a look at my last EDIT (15.02.17) .I have problem finding integra w limits.General solution MMA can find,but w limit no either.I tried `FullSimplify` but my Laptop calculate many hours and I am waiting for a response,but no luck ....

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk  Thank you for the comment. I confirm what you write, MMA can calculate the antderivative, and also its value at pi/2 (is 0) and ArcSin[Sqrt[6]/2, but I also have found no way up to now to simplify the antiderivative at the latter point. It is interesting that you get a rather short expression on the integral if you put formally a = 0 in advance, but MMA is not able to provide the Limit a->0 afterwards in finite time.

Comment: How You find this linear inhomogeneous partial difference-differential equation of first order?.Can You elaborate and updated the answer.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Thank you for your interest. I kindly ask for some patience since I have to look up my notices.

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Derivation now added. Please check it thoroughly.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze .Thanks for adding interesting notes.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer from comments.**

Let $F(t)=\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^4$.Then $F'(t)=\frac{4 e^{-t} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^3}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{t}}$ and $F(0)=0$.
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[F'(t)\right](s)=s \left(\mathcal{L}_t[F(t)](s)\right)-F(0)$$
$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{4 e^{-t} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^3}{\sqrt{\pi }
   \sqrt{t}}\right](s)=s
   \left(\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^4\right](s)\right)-0$$

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^4\right](s)=\frac{4
   \left(\mathcal{L}_t\left[\frac{\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^3}{\sqrt{t}}\right](1+s)\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } s}$$
Solve Laplace Transform with integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^3 \exp (-(s+1) t)}{\sqrt{t}} \, dt$$
Integrating with parts and substituting `Sqrt[t]=x`

$${\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{\sqrt {s+1}}}-\int_{0}^{\infty }\!6\,{\frac {
{\rm erf} \left(\sqrt {s+1}x\right) \left( {\rm erf} \left(x\right)
 \right) ^{2}{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{2}}}}{\sqrt {s+1}}}\,{\rm d}x
$$

Consider the parametric integral :
$$ I(a,b) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\!\!\!\text{erf}(ax)\,\text{erf}(bx)\,\text{erf}(bx)\,e^{-x^2}dx \tag{1}$$
and notice that:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\frac{\partial I(a,b)}{\partial b}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{8 e^{-x^2-a^2 x^2-b^2 x^2} x^2 \text{erf}(b
   x)}{\pi } \, dx=\frac{4 b}{\pi ^{3/2} \left(a^2+b^2+1\right) \left(a^2+2 b^2+1\right)}+\frac{4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+1}}\right)}{\pi
   ^{3/2} \left(a^2+b^2+1\right)^{3/2}}$$
integrating over $b\in \{0,1\}$  and $a\in \{0,\sqrt{s+1}\}$

```
 Integrate[(4 b)/((1 + a^2 + b^2) (1 + a^2 + 2 b^2) \[Pi]^(3/2)) + (
 4 ArcTan[b/Sqrt[1 + a^2 + b^2]])/((1 + a^2 + b^2)^(3/2) \[Pi]^(
 /2)), {b, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> a > 0]
 (*(4 ArcTan[1/Sqrt[2 + a^2]])/((1 + a^2) Sqrt[2 + a^2] \[Pi]^(3/2))*)

 Integrate[(4 ArcTan[1/Sqrt[2 + a^2]])/((1 + a^2) Sqrt[2 + a^2] \[Pi]^(3/2)), {a,
 0, Sqrt[s + 1]}]
 (*----*)
```

$$\int_0^{\sqrt{s+1}} \frac{4 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+a^2}}\right)}{\left(1+a^2\right) \sqrt{2+a^2} \pi ^{3/2}} \, da$$
Connect everything together:

$$\mathcal{L}_t\left[\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{t}\right)^4\right](s)=\frac{4 \sqrt{\frac{1}{s+1}}}{s}-96\frac{\int_0^{\sqrt{s+1}} \frac{\tan
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+a^2}}\right)}{\left(1+a^2\right) \sqrt{2+a^2}} \, da}{\pi ^2 s \sqrt{s+1}}$$

> .**EDIT 15.02.2017**.

Finding Integral:

$\int_0^{\sqrt{s+1}} \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2+a^2}}\right)}{\left(1+a^2\right) \sqrt{2+a^2}} \, da=\frac{1}{4} \pi  \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{s+1}\right)-\int_0^1
   \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s+1}}{\sqrt{a^2+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+2} \left(a^2+1\right)} \, da$

$\int_0^1
   \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s+1}}{\sqrt{a^2+2}}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+2} \left(a^2+1\right)} \, da
= \frac{1}{6} \left(3 \sqrt{s+1} X(s)+\pi  \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{s+1}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right)
$

where `X[s]`is:

$X(s)=\int_{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{2}}{3}\right)}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{i \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \cos (x)}{\sin ^2(x)}\right) \cos (x)\right)}{2 \left(i
   \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{s+1} \sin (x)\right)} \, dx+\int_{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{2}}{3}\right)}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{i \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \cos (x)}{\sin
   ^2(x)}\right) \cos (x)\right)}{2 \left(i \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{s+1} \sin (x)\right)} \, dx$

**Check numerics:**

```
NIntegrate[ArcTan[Sqrt[s + 1]/Sqrt[x^2 + 2]]/(Sqrt[x^2 + 2]*(x^2 + 1)) /. 
s -> 1, {x, 0, 1}]
(* 0.396282 *)

X[s_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[(I/2)*(ArcTan[2 *Cos[x]/Sin[x]^2] Cos[x])/(
I Sqrt[2] + Sqrt[s + 1]* Sin[x]), {x, ArcSin[Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[2]/3], 
Pi/2}] + 
NIntegrate[(I/2)*(ArcTan[2 *Cos[x]/Sin[x]^2] Cos[x])/(
I Sqrt[2] - Sqrt[s + 1]* Sin[x]), {x, ArcSin[Sqrt[3]*Sqrt[2]/3], 
Pi/2}]
1/6 (\[Pi] ArcTan[Sqrt[1 + s]/Sqrt[3]] + 3 Sqrt[1 + s] X[s]) /. 
s -> 1 // N
(* 0.396282 *)
Ok works.
```

Finding a integral :

$\int_{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{2}}{3}\right)}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \frac{i \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 \cos (x)}{\sin ^2(x)}\right) \cos (x)\right)}{2 \left(i
   \sqrt{2}-\sqrt{s+1} \sin (x)\right)} \, dx=?$

MMA has problem to caluculate this integral with limits,but without limits is:
where `a` is `Sqrt[s+1]`

```
 Integrate[(I/2)*(ArcTan[2 *Cos[x]/Sin[x]^2] Cos[x])/(
 I Sqrt[2] -a*Sin[x]), x]
 (*the result is a very long*)
```

Comment: Call the integral B(s). Differentiating with respect to s I found this formula. Don't know if it is useful 

$$B(s) = \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{s+1}{y^2+2}}\right)}{\left(y^2+1\right) \sqrt{y^2+2}} \, dy=-\int_0^s \frac{\cot^{-1}\left(\sqrt{z+3}\right)}{2 \sqrt{z+1} (z+2) \sqrt{z+3}} \, dz+\frac{ \pi}{4}  \arctan\left(\sqrt{s+1}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2}{32}$$

At $s = 0$ we have
$$B(s=0) = \int_0^1 \frac{\cot ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{y^2+2}\right)}{\left(y^2+1\right) \sqrt{y^2+2}} \, dy=\frac{\pi ^2}{32}$$

Comment: It seems that the formula in your update is incorrect. It looks as if it was meant as a consequence of the relations arctan(x) + arccot(x) = pi/2 and arccot(x) = arctan(1/x) but the argument in the arctan on the right hand side of your formula is wrong.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze. Yes you are right.Thanks :)